# Configure iptables to secure a server running Docker containers

Tags: nginx, security, iptables, docker

I try to use Docker to run 2 containers (the issue is not specific to them):

- MySQL (official container)
- Redmine (official container)

Each container has a forwarded port:

- MySQL: `127.0.0.1:3000 -> 3000/tcp`
- Redmine: `127.0.0.1:3306 -> 3306/tcp`

As you can see, the goal is to make them accessible **only within the host**.

A Nginx server (not installed via Docker) listens to the port 80 and redirects any request to the Redmine container port (using proxy functionnalities: `proxy_pass` etc.).

All works perfectly at this point, when I go to the server ip, I can access to Redmine.

But, I'd want to add some security using iptables.
So, the goal is to:

- DROP all by default (this point is ok)
- Allow Docker to make its business only within the local host
- Allow the containers to access the Internet (to download dependencies, updates...)
- Allow the access to SSH and Nginx (ok too)

First, I tried to add the `--iptables=false` option to stop docker messing with my iptables.
After a reboot, I thought that, with clean iptables (all politics are set to `ACCEPT` by default, so nothing is done yet), all would work well. But that's not the case, I get a `"502 Bad Gateway"` response from Nginx. I don't really understand why Docker is unable to work without adding additional rules (if all is open, it should work... No?).

I tried to read the docs about advanced networking in Docker, I also tried multiple tutorials, but I can't find what is blocking Docker:

- https://fralef.me/docker-and-iptables.html
- https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/articles/networking/

I'm not a Linux/Docker/SysAdmin expert so maybe, it will be obvious for some of you (at least, I wish!).

Don't hesitate to ask me more details if needed.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: What is your Linux distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Docker by default adds iptables rules so that ports exposed to the host can be accessed.
You can try adding this to the DOCKER-USER chain:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 ! -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

This will drop all packets that are coming from the external interface (in this case eth0) and have no loopback origin.
This might need to be executed *after* you start the docker service.

Update: As Luca said you probably only need either

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -j DROP
```

or

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER ! -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

Comment: how can packets with source ip == 127/8 possibly reach eth0?

Comment: True, you probably need only one of those conditions, not both.